# Merging, then splitting files

Tags: bash

Using a `for` loop, I can merge all of the files in a directory that end with `*.txt`:

```
for filename in *.txt; do
    cat "${filename}"
    echo
done > output.txt
```

After doing this, I will run `output.txt` through various scripts, in which the text will be changed considerably. After that, I want to split the files, at the same places at which they were merged, into different files (`output01.txt`, `output02.txt`, etc.).

- How can I split the files at the same place they were merged?

This cannot be based on line number, because the scripts will add \t in places.

I think a solution that might work is to place "@@@@@@@@@" at the end of each of the initial `*.txt` files before merging them, but I don't know how to get `BASH` to split the files again at that mark.

Comment: Easier way of concatenating the files: `cat *.txt > output.txt`.

Comment: Run the scripts on the split files, individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of that `for` loop for concatenating, you can just use `cat *.txt`.

Anyway, why don't you just perform the scripts on each file independently within the `for` loop?

If you really want to combine and re-segregate, you can use:

```
for filename in *.txt; do
    cat "${filename}"
    echo "@@@@@"
done > output.txt

# Pass output.txt through whatever

awk 'BEGIN { fileno = 1; file = sprintf("output%02d.txt", fileno) }; 
     { if($1 ~ /@@@@@/) { fileno++; 
                          file = sprintf("output%02d.txt", fileno); 
                          next } 
       else print >file 
     }' output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical answer would be:

```
tar c *.txt > output.txt
```

You could split/unmerge them exactly by doing

```
tar xf output.txt # in the current directory
tar x -C /tmp/splitfiles/ -f output.txt
```

Now if you really want to do stuff like that in a loop and extract to stdout/a pipe, you could:

```
while read fname < <(tar tf output.txt)
do
    # extract named to pipe
    tar -xOf output.txt "$fname" | myprogram "$fname" 
done
```

However, that would possibly not be very efficient. You could consider just doing

```
while read fname < <(tar x -v -C /tmp/splitfiles/ -f output.txt)
do
    # handle extracted file
    myprogram "/tmp/splitfiles/$fname" 
    unlink "/tmp/splitfiles/$fname" # drop the temp file
done
```

This will be completely asynchronous (so if extraction or even the transmission of the archive is slow, the first files can already be processed while waiting for more data to arrive).

See also my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8341221/85371 (look for the **`older answer`** part, since that question was changed to be very specific later)

Answer (score 1):

As Fredrik wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8544732/934599) you can use `csplit` to split your merged file.